# Any switches powered over Ethernet?

Tags: home-networking, ethernet, switch

My home has a single Ethernet jack going to most rooms. In some rooms I'd like to expand that into several ports so I'm going to be putting a small switch next to each one. All the switches I've seen require access to power. It's not terrible but it'd be much nicer if I had one that was powered over the Ethernet uplink instead using PoE. Does anyone make such a product?

Comment: a quick google search yielded quite a few POE-powered switches.  Try searching for "POE-powered switch".

Comment: 1 quick google-search: http://www.amazon.com/POEmax-8000-PoE-Powered-Ethernet-Switch/dp/B00322Q2UK

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not that I have seen directly, however, if the source provides POE, you can always use a POE injector to power a low powered switch.

(First picture found by Google as I couldn't find an example including the wires)

[image]

Although, being passive, I believe that this product will most likely use the spare pairs of cable and not give you a gig.

I have seen the following from TP Link which is rated for a full gig: [linky](http://uk.tp-link.com/products/details/?categoryid=234&model=TL-POE150S#down) - and if your source does not provide POE, you can always combine it with : [linky](http://uk.tp-link.com/products/details/?categoryid=234&model=TL-POE10R)